# Weierstrass Elliptic Function and p-function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

### Definitions

> [(Simpler form of) Weierstrass elliptic function] In the projective space, it is an elliptic curve; $y^2z = x^3 + Axz^2 + Bz^3$

> [Weierstrass p-function] In the projective space, it is a periodic function;
> $\wp(z, \omega_1, \omega_2) = \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda - \{ 0 \}} (\frac{1}{(z - \lambda)^2} - \frac{1}{\lambda ^ 2})$

### Question

Is the link between these two concepts in the differential equation of p-function, i.e.,

- $\wp'^2 = 4 \wp^3 + g_2 \wp + g_3$ for some functions $g_2, g_3$ and now this is taking the same form as Weierstrass elliptic function
- Elliptic function is, as in projective space, a "homogenised" version of this DE
  ?

Thank you for taking time to check my question!

Comment: Yes, indeed the the functions $\wp$ and $\wp'$ are periodic on $\Lambda$. Then, the morphism $z \in \mathbb{C}/\Lambda-\{ 0 \} \mapsto (\wp(z), \wp'(z))$ is an isomorphism into the dehomogenized elliptic curve. We can compactify this morphism by sending $z=0$ to the point at the infinity.

Comment: Got it! Makes sense! Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Let me point out that the Weierstrass $\wp$-function is not itself an elliptic curve, like you've written on the second definition, but rather gives rise to an elliptic curve, via the map @ÝTAN defined.

Comment: @Fotis oh! Thank you for your correction and for your follow up! I edited my post!